# 2 flexible divs resize and split (1/5) with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, resize, responsive-design

I have an application where the design is:

```
header (100%)
____________________________
side | contents
bar  |
```

The design is flexible (aka when resizing the sidebar and contents widths readjust) 
I need the sidebar to be around 1 of 5 or 30% and the rest filled by the "contents" div

I am using jQuery but I am stuck with the calculation,

```
layoutWidth = $(window).width();
sidebarWidth = layoutWidth / 5;
contentsWidth = ...so how can I find the remainder of the division?

$('.sidebar').width(sidebarWidth);
$('.contents').width(contentsWidth);
$('.layout-content, .sidebar, .contents').height( layoutHeight );
```

Both divs are floats by the way.

Tried:
contentsWidth = layoutWidth - sidebarWidth;

but does not work...

I don't want to do it with CSS because it is not consistent across older/mobile browsers and besides all the app code is in jQuery.

Comment: contentsWidth = (layoutWidth - sidebarWidth); ?

Comment: A console log I did prints: layoutWidth 1920, sidebarWidth 384, contentsWidth 1536, however the floats seem to cascade...

Answer (score 0):

No need for javascript.. you can do it with just CSS (*just a single floated element*)

```
.header{width:100%;}
.sidebar{width:30%;float:left}
.content{margin-left:30%;}
```

**Demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/WFH3z/1/

Answer (score 0):

Frameworks such as bootstrap's (getbootstrap.com) or jquerymobile's grid systems can be used to do this.  If you have browsers prior to IE 8, support begins to wane, but jquerymobile seems to have better support for IE 7 than bootstrap.  There are techniques for overcoming them, and in this case, using CSS would be considered more pure.

That said, some browsers may have a different implementation of things like margins, borders, and widths, so you may not be able to use 100% of the width (something the above mentioned frameworks take into account in their grid systems).  If you wanted to fix your code, you could scale back on the widths a little (this is not tailored to all browsers and may not be what you want), but I prefer @Gaby's answer over this:

```
var layoutWidth = $(window).width();
$('.sidebar').width(layoutWidth * .19);
$('.contents').width(layoutWidth * .79);
```